# How to array a list using the quantity of an item to show a line per item of that order

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I would like to have a "row per product" for all orders purchased from my WooCommerce store. This means if a user purchasing more than 1 of the same item in a single order, I would like a sheet to show a row per item, but also displaying basic info from the main order row like First Name, Email address, and Phone number.

Play here - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IYd7MiT83ZY3-JhMa-2ddhPUhqhcCQFLAdKZcnLBVFM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(
 Data!A2:A&"♦"&Data!B2:B&"♦"&Data!C2:C&"♦"&Data!D2:D&"♠", 
 Data!D2:D)), "♠")), "♦"))
```

[image: 0]